# AWS EC2: SSH works but I am unable to use my VNC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vnc, connection-refused

I am running a Linux EC2 instance with TigerVNC viewer. This has worked for about six months until my EC2 instance recorded an error and I had to stop it from the Instance Console. I have restarted, but am now unable to access the GUI. SSH access from the console works and I can run commands in the terminal. I have checked the 'vncserver :1' command and am told that a VNC server is running, but when I open TigerVNC it crashes before asking for a password with the terminal error 'channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused'. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Have you updated IP of your instance in vncviewer?

Comment: I can sign in using the terminal. In the past I have managed to use the 'localhost' command from the AWS tutorial, this time I have also tried specifying the IP address, but got the same error.

Comment: What do you mean by 'localhost'? Have you setup ssh tunnel from instance to your local workstation?

Comment: Yes, when I set the VNC up I followed the AWS tutorial which says to set up the ssh with the command 'ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 -i PEM_FILE ec2-user@INSTANCE_IP'. This has worked in the past and still allows me to run commands in the terminal. The error occurs when I start the VNC viewer and specify the VNC server as 'localhost:1'.

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue and it doesnt resolve with solution that OP has provided below. Can someone please help?

Comment: replying to my comment from above. Nothing helped and i finally reinstalled to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging, the solution is to remove an X11 file. The following line in the terminal after using the ssh worked 'rm -rvf /tmp/.X11-unix/X1'.

Comment: I ran into similar issue with tigervnc and this is not working. Do you have suggestions from your experience when you explored this?

Comment: The basic idea is to remove the old (corrupted) VNC server so that you can reinstall a working version. If you can find the path to the server that the instance thinks is running, you can remove it. Mine was as above.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I reinstalled a version and it finally started working. Everything else i explored wasnt helping much.